# How to concatenate multiple CString

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, cstring

All functions return CString, this is a MFC code and must compile in 32 & 64 bits.

Currently I'm using

> ```
> CString sURI = GetURL();
> sURI += GetMethod();
> sURI += "?";
> sURI += GetParameters();
> ```

Exists any manner to do the same like:

> ```
> CString sURI = GetURL() + GetMethod() + "?" + GetParameters();
> ```

Comment: Did you try it?  What (if any) compiler errors did you get?

Comment: Have you tried it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx looks like it should work...

Answer (score 5):

Problem is that "?" of type "const char*" is, and its + operator does not take right hand operand of type CString. You have to convert "?" to CString like this:

```
CString sURI = GetURL() + GetMethod() + _T("?") + GetParameters();
```

Comment: _T converts a character or string to its Unicode counterpart, I think you meant CString("?")

Comment: That is not true. _T converts the string to a proper character type, which depends on the project options. If you choose Unicode in project options, it converts string to const wchar*, otherwise it gives a const char* back.

Answer (score 3):

As long as all those functions return a `CString` object, then it should be fine to use the `+` operator for concatenation.

Otherwise use the `CString _T(const char *)` function to wrap your regular C strings and make them a CString.